# Copy line with subtitution before the line itself with sed

Tags: linux, sed

Here's my input

```
dummy
This is a line
dummy
dummy
this is another line
```

the output should be

```
dummy
# This is a line
This is a line
dummy
dummy
# this is another line
this is another line
```

Which is quite simple IMO...

Just tried the sed below but this wouldn't add the pattern found. It just prints # above the line.

```
 sed -i '/^this/I i\ '#' & ' $file
```

Thoughts? Thanks.

Seems like this syntax is not the right way to achieve this.

Comment: `sed -r 's/(.*)/# \1\n\1/'` does it for me

Comment: @g00se : well, it does work only if every line of the input contains 'this' -not my case actually, sorry for not having pointed this out

Comment: *well, it does work only if every line of the input contains 'this' -not my case actually, sorry for not having pointed this out* Fix that easily with `sed -r 's/^([Tt]his.*)/# \1\n\1/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/dummy/I!s/.*/# &\n&/' file
```

If a line does not contain the word `dummy`, then duplicate the line with the first duplicate prepended with `#` .

Comment: The OP apparently want to duplicate-comment all lines starting with `this` (case insensitive) and leave the others unmodified. So, `sed '/^this/Is/.*/# &\n&/' file` is probably better. And this looks POSIX to me, not just GNU sed. Am I wrong?

Comment: @potong :
thanks again. Would you be kind enough to explain to me the &\n& trick?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : defo ;)

Comment: @MichaelClaret the `s/.*/# &\n&/` basically scoops up the whole line in the left hand side and refers to it as `&` in the right hand side. Thus by inserting `# ` and `\n` (a newline) between two `&`s the line is duplicated and the first line prepended by `# `.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^this/I{h;s/^/# /;G}' input_file
# This is a line
This is a line
# this is another line
this is another line
```

or slurping the entire input

```
$ sed -z 's/this[^\n]*\n/# &&/Ig' input_file
# This is a line
This is a line
# this is another line
this is another line
```

If `awk` is an option

```
$ awk '/^[Tt]his/{print "# "$0}1' input_file
# This is a line
This is a line
# this is another line
this is another line
```